# How to change encoding of the tag with eye3D module to iso-8859-5?

Tags: python, encoding, mp3, python-2.5

The file can have `cp1251` and `utf-8` encodings. I should:

1. delete id3 v2 tags
2. change encoding of id3 v1 tags to `iso-8859-5`

I do the following:

```
def getTagStr (tagUnicStr):
    # gets the 1byte 8bits string, as written in the tag, from the unicode, returned by tag.get*
    # taken from tag2utf-0.16 by Kopats Andrei
    ls = []
    for i in range(0,len(tagUnicStr)):
        if (ord(tagUnicStr[i]) in range(256)):
            ls.append(chr(ord(tagUnicStr[i])))
        else:
            ls.append(tagUnicStr[i])
    Str8 = ''.join(ls)
    return Str8

trackInfo = eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(path)
tag = trackInfo.getTag()
tag.link(path)
mp3artist = tag.getArtist() # contains Russian characters
mp3artist = getTagStr(mp3artist)
mp3encoding = 'utf-8'
try:
    # pseudo utf-8 encoding
    mp3artist = mp3artist.decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError, err:
    # cp1251
    mp3artist = mp3artist.decode('cp1251')
    mp3encoding = 'cp1251'
except UnicodeEncodeError, err:
    # utf-8
    pass

tag.setArtist(mp3artist.encode('iso-8859-5'))
tag.update()
```

and it fails with the following error at the last line:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 1-5: ordinal not in range(256)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is very unclear about it, but it appears that eyeD3 only accepts tags that are either 1/ Unicode, or 2/ bytes encoded with your current locale's encoding (which is then used to convert the tag back into Unicode anyway).

Consequently, I don't think your approach can work at all. Basically, you can't pass arbitrarily encoded data to eyeD3, like you're attempting to do in the second-to-last line of your script.

eyeD3 does seems to provide encoding-related facilities, though:

```
tag.setTextEncoding(encoding)
```

However, from reading the code of that function, only a few specific encodings are allowed by the ID3 spec, and iso-8859-5 is not among them.

The ID3 spec thus simply doesn't appear to allow what you are attempting to do. If what you are trying to do here is *work around* that spec, eyeD3, which follows it, is not likely to help, I'm afraid.

Perhaps you'll want to rephrase your question in terms of exactly what you're trying to achieve by fiddling with tag encodings? Then other solutions could be suggested.